# HTML 'img' Tag do not operate in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

Sorry for poor English.
Image html tag do not operate and display Xbox in WebBrowser Control.
C# Source)

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(false);
webBrowser1.Document.Write(str_html);
webBrowser1.Refresh();
```

HTML ex)

```
<html><head></head><body><img src="d:/report/1.bmp" width=1000></body></html>
```

[xBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEISA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning it to an object.

This is an example that I used and works:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><head></head><body><img src='C:/srcFolder/imagelocationURL.png'/></body></html>"
```

Comment: Dotnet Version is 4. Is it making problem?

Comment: and VisualStudio2017